# Issue with multiple in-line references by some author using bibtex + natbib + apacite

Tags: natbib, apa-style, inline

When I have multiple papers to refer to in the same breath by the same author, the second reference year always prints as `0` and with no space after the comma, even though the full reference is indeed available in my bibliography file. So while my PDF contains...

[image: image showing Jackendoff (2006,0).]

...I want it instead to read **and Parallel Architecture (PA: Jackendoff, 2006, 2002).** No matter how I fiddle with the citekeys I can't get it to output correctly.

The command in question is written `\citep[PA:][]{jackendoff2006, jackendoff2002}`, with the relevant packages used being:

`\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}`

and these commands just before ending the document:

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{../ReferenceFilePhD}`

Everything else works fine, including multiple in-line references by *different* authors. So anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

---

UPDATE: Thanks for your requests! As you know, I'm new here, but I'll do my best with an MWE -- I just don't know how to integrate the `bibtex` formatting of my references with a document-internal call to them. Here is the true MWE (which does output the error I get), referring to an external reference file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}  
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\dots and Parallel Architecture \citep[PA:][]{jackendoff2006, jackendoff2002} \dots
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{../ReferenceFilePhD}
\end{document}
```

And the reference entries are:

```
@book{jackendoff2002,
Author = {Jackendoff, Ray},
Publisher = {Oxford, UK: Oxford University Press},
Title = {Foundations of language: Brain, meaning, grammar, evolution},
Year = {2002}}
```

...and...

```
@article{jackendoff2006,
Author = {Jackendoff, Ray},
Journal = {Brain Research},
Pages = {2--22},
Title = {A parallel architecture perspective on language processing},
Volume = {1146},
Year = {2006}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: At a minimum, do post the complete entries for `jackendoff2006` and `jackendoff2002`.

Comment: Right on! Please see the additions above -- are they sufficient? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old request but since I can't seem to find any direct answers, I though I might post it here to help people with the same problem:

just change

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Comment: i have the same problem.
the answer proposed to change \bibliographystyle{apalike}
to
\bibliographystyle{apacite} dosen't work for me.