# Apacite natbib problem with multiple in-text citation - two items from same authors not displayed well

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, apacite

I hope it will not be considered a duplicate, but I have the same issue as here: [Issue with multiple in-line references by some author using bibtex + natbib + apacite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222413/issue-with-multiple-in-line-references-by-some-author-using-bibtex-natbib-ap)

The linked question received a workaround (changing bibliography style), but not a solution. I would like to stick to my current bib style, AND solve the problem. Contextualizing the MWE in my case, is the following:

```
\documentclass[]{book}  
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\begin{document}
....effort in studying and formalizing innovation practices \citep{pavitt1982,pavitt1984,dosi1988}
\bibliography{riprova}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\end{document}
```

and the references entries are:

```
@Article{pavitt1982,
    author  = {Pavitt, K.},
    journal = {Research Policy},
    title   = {{R}\&{D}, patenting and innovative activities: A statistical exploration},
    year    = {1982},
    pages   = {33--51},
    volume  = {11},
    issue   = {1},
}
@Article{pavitt1984,
    author  = {Pavitt, K.},
    journal = {Research Policy},
    title   = {Sectoral patterns of technical change: towards a taxonomy and a theory},
    year    = {1984},
    pages   = {343--373},
    volume  = {13},
}
@Article{dosi1988,
    author  = {Dosi, G.},
    journal = {Journal of Economic Literature},
    title   = {Sources, Procedures, and Microeconomic Effects of Innovation},
    year    = {1988},
    pages   = {1120--1171},
    volume  = {26},
    issue   = {3},
}
```

The current output is below at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc2TW.png). Is any of you aware of solutions? I did not want to switch to apacite as .bst because I do not want the URLs and DOIs of my references in the bibliography of this document.

Thanks for the attention,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You mustn't load both `apacite` and `natbib`. Give `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` a try.

Comment: You also can't use the `apa` bibliography style with `apacite`. You must use the `apacite` bibliography style. If that's not what you want, don't load the `apacite` package at all. Using the `apacite` bibliography style with the `apacite` package is not a "workaround", it's how the package is meant to be used.

Comment: Hi! First of all, thanks for answering back.
@Mico tried, but same output unfortunately.

Comment: @AlanMunn I understand I was mistaken, thanks for making me notice. So, do you I have any option to keep using natbib and having the final references in simple "apa" bst? Or even better, stick to apacite but removing DOIs and "retrieved from" fields? Thanks again,

Comment: I would switch to `biblatex` and use its `apa` style with options `url=false,doi=false`.  Or if you don't need fully conforming APA style in all the details, use the `ext-authoryear` style with the same options and tweak the formatting as you require. Don't try to modify the `biblatex-apa` style itself, since it's really too complex and not designed for modification.  Alternatively, try using `natbib` with the `apalike` bibliography style.  See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) for some explanation of the diffe